# How do I count all possible sums of array elements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop, if-statement

I’m kind of stuck with my code and I can’t find where the problem is. My task is to find the closest sum in the array to the x value and amount of indexes to sum must not exceed n-value. Indexes to sum might not be consecutive, so the closest sum might be indexes(0,2,3) instead of (0,1,2).
I’ve written some code, but it does not work with n value bigger than 4.

In my code value of sums(n) if called  «towns» and x value is called «miles».

Here comes the code

```
  for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++){
       sum=ls.get(i);
      counterTowns=1;
          if(sum<miles&&counterTowns<towns){
        for(int j=i+1;j<ls.size();j++){
                sum+=ls.get(j);
                counterTowns++;
                if(counterTowns==towns){
                    if(sum<=miles){
                        if(sum>temp){
                            result=sum;
                        }
                        temp=result;
                  }

                    sum=ls.get(i);
                    counterTowns=1;
             if(towns>2){   // I think the problem is in this line
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be more clear, "ls" is the ArrayList of Integers.
For example:
ArrayList is {50, 55, 56, 57, 58};
And  towns=3, miles = 163 expected output is 163 which is the sum of 50+56+57.
When towns <=3 it works just fine with different miles, but if towns >3 it does not provide right output.
For example, if ArrayList is{91, 74, 73, 85, 73, 81, 87}
and miles= 331 and towns is 4 result is 30 instead of 331( result of 91+74+85+81).

I hope my question is clear and if not feel free to ask any questions.
Thank you in advance.
Peace and love!!!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]? What is the declaration of the method that contains the `for` loop in the code in your question? Is `ls` a `java.util.List`? If it is, can you provide sample elements that it contains? Can you provide a sample value for `miles` and for `towns`?

Comment: I've edited my question and while doing it I guess I found the problem. It must be that my code adds elements consecutively, but it should try each possible element with each index, but still, I'm not sure how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want all the combinations of `towns` elements in the `ArrayList`.
Then you want to sum all the elements in each combination and find the smallest difference between the sum and `miles`.

I found the following code for finding all possible combinations of `n` elements in  an array. Hence I used an array of `int` rather than an `ArrayList`. Refer to [Print all possible combinations of r elements in a given array of size n](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/). I copied the code from that Web page and modified it so that it solves your problem. Note that I used your sample list and value for `towns`. Explanations of the code appear after it.

Also note that the comments in the code are from the original code that I copied.

```java
public class TownsKms {
    private static int counter;
    private static int kms;
    private static int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private static int[] minArr;

    /* arr[]  ---> Input Array 
    data[] ---> Temporary array to store current combination 
    start & end ---> Staring and Ending indexes in arr[] 
    index  ---> Current index in data[] 
    r ---> Size of a combination to be printed */
    static void combinationUtil(int arr[],
                                int data[],
                                int start, 
                                int end,
                                int index,
                                int r) {
        // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it 
        if (index == r) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j=0; j<r; j++) {
                sum += data[j];
            }
            int diff = Math.abs(kms - sum);
            if (diff < min) {
                min = diff;
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, minArr, 0, minArr.length);
            }
            return; 
        } 
  
        // replace index with all possible elements. The condition 
        // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element 
        // at index will make a combination with remaining elements 
        // at remaining positions 
        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++) {
            data[index] = arr[i]; 
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r); 
        } 
    } 
  
    // The main function that prints all combinations of size r 
    // in arr[] of size n. This function mainly uses combinationUtil() 
    static void printCombination(int arr[], int n, int r) {
        // A temporary array to store all combination one by one 
        int data[]=new int[r]; 
  
        // Print all combination using temprary array 'data[]' 
        combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r); 
    }

    /**
     * Start here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {91, 74, 73, 85, 73, 81, 87};
        int towns = 4;
        minArr = new int[towns];
        kms = 331;
        int n = arr.length;
        printCombination(arr, n, towns);
        int sum = 0;
        boolean first = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < minArr.length; i++) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            sum += minArr[i];
            System.out.print(minArr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(" = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Rather than add more parameters to the methods, I decided to use class members instead. Also, rather than `miles`, I named the variable `kms`, i.e. kilometers.

The difference between the sum of the elements in a given combination and the value of `kms` may be negative. You want the difference that is closest to zero. Hence I calculate the *absolute* difference which is why I call method `abs()` of class `Math`.

The only thing that is unclear from your question is whether the size of a combination must be precisely the value of `towns` or can it be any size from one up to `towns`. In other words, if `towns` equals 4, do you want all combinations of 4 elements from the list or do you also want to check combinations of 1, 2 and 3 elements as well? If the latter, then you need to repeat the above code and each time change the value of `towns`, i.e. set `towns = 1` and run the above code. Then set `towns = 2`, etc. But remember **not** to reset `min`.